# How can I store data using javascript application and Html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I asked myself this morning if it's possible to create a javascript app and html and being able to store data localy without using any server?
Do you have any suggestions?

by the way I tried to use json files using this code

```
            $.getJSON("./data/cities.json", function(json) {
                console.log(json); // this will show the info it in firebug console
            });
```

but I got this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/YYY/App/data/cities.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

Comment: localStorage https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: but where data are stored?

Comment: @user3429578 it's stored on the client's computer. localstorage is a key-value pair, with the keys and values being strings. Every time a user visits your site from the same browser, it is stored, as you said, locally and not on the server.

Comment: and is there any way for gettting those data and store them in a file?

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed store the data with localStorage, but if you are going to save to a file I suggest on looking into following libraries:

[FileSave.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js)

- You can stringify your json with 
  `jsonFile = JSON.stringify(jsonFile)`
- After that you can download the stringified file with 
  `var blob = new Blob([jsonFile], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
  saveAs(blob, "jsonStringified.txt");`

Web applications don't generally have access to the client side's file system. Is there any particular reason why you would need to save them to a file? UPDATE: The lack of file access is also the reason why your file loading doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can by using [html5 local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: sure but I would like to create an independent file in a specific folder without getting the download popup